# Vim Coc error message when executing :CocCommand clangd.install

Tags: vim, clangd

I have installed vim coc (https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) and clangd for the rest of my machines with no issues. But when I tried to `:CocCommand clangd.install` yesterday I got

```
[coc.nvim] Failed to install clangd language server: TypeError: Expected signal to be an instanceof AbortSignal
You may want to install it manually. See https://clangd.llvm.org/installation.html.
```

PS: The previous step i.e. `:CocInstall coc-clangd` worked just fine

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:CocUpdate` to upgrade `coc-clangd` to v0.4.14 will fix this.